# PostgreSQL ST_LineLocatePoint function

Tags: postgresql

I am using the ST_LineLocatePoint function from PostgreSQL. According to what I have read, the description for this function is as follows:

> Returns a float between 0 and 1 representing the location of the closest point on LineString to the given Point, as a fraction of total 2D line length.

I am using a 3D LineString and I want to get the 3D distance to a point.

Is there an equivalent 3D function for ST_LineLocatePoint?